# TypeError: this is undefined - {this.props.sections}

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to set values for a component by fathers prop, but this error pops and I don't have a clue on where is the real error

This is my component code:

```
import React from 'react';

import './styles.css';

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

export default function Actions() {
  return (
    <div className="actions">
      <FontAwesomeIcon className="icon" icon={this.props.fa} size="lg" />
      <h1>{this.props.sections}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And this is my father component code:

```
import React from 'react';

import './styles.css'

import Actions from "../Actions/index"

// - - - FONT-AWESOME
import { faExternalLinkAlt } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <div className="navbar">
      <Actions sections={"Lançamentos"} fa={faExternalLinkAlt}/>
      <Actions sections={"Processos"} fa={faExternalLinkAlt}/>
      <Actions sections={"Paineis"} fa={faExternalLinkAlt}/>
      <Actions sections={"Contratos"} fa={faExternalLinkAlt}/>
      <Actions sections={"Relatórios"} fa={faExternalLinkAlt}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: you didn't write an instantiable component, you wrote a [simple function](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components), so there is no `this`, let alone `this.props`. If you have a function, its argument should be `props`, and that's what you tap into for the return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In functional components, you don't need to reference `this`

**Class based component**

Definition:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render () {
      <div>{this.props.sampleProp}</div>
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<MyComponent sampleProps={someValue} />
```

**Functional component**

Definition:

```
function MyComponent({sampleProp}) {
  return (
    <div>{sampleProp}</div>
  )
}
```

Usage:

```
<MyComponent sampleProp={someValue} />
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use functional components you need to pass props as argument of the function, you also don't have 'this'.

```
export default function Actions(props) {
  return (
    <div className="actions">
      <FontAwesomeIcon className="icon" icon={props.fa} size="lg" />
      <h1>{props.sections}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

That would be your final code, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is for class components. For functional components it gets from the function arguments:

```
import React from 'react';

import './styles.css';

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

export default function Actions(props) {
  return (
    <div className="actions">
      <FontAwesomeIcon className="icon" icon={props.fa} size="lg" />
      <h1>{props.sections}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `this` keyword from the function component, and pass `props` to the function too, like this:

```
import React from 'react';

import './styles.css';

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

export default function Actions(props) {
  return (
    <div className="actions">
      <FontAwesomeIcon className="icon" icon={props.fa} size="lg" />
      <h1>{props.sections}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```